# Checkbox click to trigger POST route

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap-4

I have a nodejs /express app and would like to use a checkbox click to trigger a POST route so that I can update my database with whether a corresponding element is checked or not. I am using a Bootstrap4 checkbox form (see code below) within an ejs view. I dont want to use a submit button or jquery. I thought of wrapping the input with  tags containing the route and action but that doesnt trigger the route.Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" name="checked" type="checkbox" 
value="true"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your checkbox in form tag and add onClick event handler to submit the form, as following:

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="checked" type="checkbox" value="true" onChange="this.form.submit()">
</form>
```

use **action** to specify server endpoint

But keep in mind that every time the form submitted the page will be reloaded. If you don't want such behavior you have to use Ajax. but it is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Nice simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `onClick` event on the input element.

```js
function task(e)
{
  
  if(e.target.checked)
  {
    ///do post request with 1 in parameter
    console.log("do post request with 1 in parameter");
  }
  else
  {
    ///do post request with 0 parameter
    console.log("do post request with 0 parameter");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="task(event);"/>
```

Or if you are using jQuery check out this answer: [how to send a post request on checkbox check/uncheck event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681270/how-to-send-a-post-request-on-checkbox-check-uncheck-event)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are using Bootstrap you can use the jQuery `change()` event handler to trigger the post.

```
<label><input id="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked>&nbsp;Check me</label>

$('#form-check-input').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $.post(ajax_url, function(data) {
      // success handler
    })
  }
})
```